# Spring Security unable to generate/map default login page at /spring_security_login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I noticed if i mention a pattern or enter a RequestMatcher reference to the HTTP container, the spring_security_login default page isn't generated. I would like to know why. Is it expected that in such scenarios (which drive to multiple http config elements) we need to provide our own login pages and authentication logic?

This is the config I am referring to.

```
<http pattern="/somearea/**" authentication-manager-ref="authMgr"  use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" request-matcher="ant">
```

This is how my web.xml looks like, if that is of interest. Not very fancy. :-)

```
<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Also, if i make my own login page which calls j_spring_security_check, the j_spring_security_check mapping isn't found as well. Please let me know if any more config info is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that both [http@pattern](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-http-pattern) and [http@request-matcher-ref](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-http-request-matcher-ref) both decide if the  block is used. Since neither `/spring_security_login` or `/j_spring_security_check` match the provided pattern (`/somearea/`) the  block will not be used.

To resolve this, you need to ensure your form-login@login-processing-url is configured to look at a request that matches your `http@pattern`. You will also need to specifying a login page and ensure you render the custom login page. For example, assuming you ensure the URL /login renders a login page the following configuration will work:

```
<http pattern="/somearea/**" authentication-manager-ref="authMgr"  use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" request-matcher="ant">
    <form-login login-processing-url="/somearea/login" loginPage="/login"/>    
</http>
```

Alternatively, you could create a separate  block that just performs the authentication:

```
<http pattern="/somearea/**" authentication-manager-ref="authMgr"  use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" request-matcher="ant">

</http>
<http authentication-manager-ref="authMgr" use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" request-matcher="ant">    
</http>
```

Keep in mind that each  configuration is distinct and is only applicable when the pattern or request-matcher-ref matches.

Comment: The login-processing-url has me curious now. :-) Thanks.